# Does Tcl exec's 2>@stdout work like 2>@1?

Tags: tcl, ipc

According to exec's documentation, `2>@fileId` should redirect the executed process' standard error stream to the file identified by `fileId` in the calling process. `stdout` is the file ID of the calling process' standard output stream.

Then why does it seem like stderr of the called process is written into exec's result instead, as described for `2>@1`, not for `2>@stdout`?

EDIT: I am using Tcl 8.6 on Linux, a platform on which exec should not have any known limitations.

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh
# This file is saved as redir.tcl .

set output [exec bash -c "1>&2 echo warning; echo usual output" 2>@stdout]
set logFileId [open "tcl_process_log.txt" "w"]
puts $logFileId $output
```

From a command line:

```
$ ./redir.tcl
$ # Note that nothing appears on the screen, even though only the subprocess' output
$ # is written to the log file after being captured by exec, not the parent Tcl process'.
$ cat tcl_process_log.txt
warning
usual output
```

On the other hand, redirecting to the parent's standard error stream works as described by exec's documentation:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh
# This file is saved as redir_stderr.tcl .

set output [exec bash -c "1>&2 echo warning; echo usual output" 2>@stderr]
set logFileId [open "tcl_process_error_log.txt" "w"]
puts $logFileId $output
```

From a command line:

```
$ ./redir_stderr.tcl 
warning
$ cat tcl_process_error_log.txt 
usual output
```

According to my interpretation, both cases use the `2>fileId` feature, with `fileID` being "stdout" and "stderr" in the above cases, respectively. Redirecting to stderr behaves as documented, redirecting to stdout does not and behaves the same as when redirecting to the called process' stdout, not that of the caller.

Why do the two behave differently?

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting. Looks like it might be a bug.

Comment: That's what I assumed, but wanted to ask more people before jumping into conclusions as i'm not a Tcl guru. EDIT: I also reproduced it with Tcl 8.3, so if it is a bug, it may have been there from basically the beginning of these features' existence.

Comment: “There in 8.3” doesn't surprise me; the subprocess pipeline launching engine has changed extremely little since at least Tcl 7.3…